# Remove zero values from two arrays to plot them on a scatter plot (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I have this part of a code:

```
for b in range(len(edad_promedio) - 1):
    contador = 0
    for c in range(len(eNdi_grafico)):
        if (edad_grafico[c] >= edad_promedio[b] and edad_grafico[c] < edad_promedio[b + 1] and eNdi_grafico[c] != -33.00):
            promedio = eNdi_grafico[c] + promedio
            contador += 1
    if (contador == 0):
        contador = 1
    eNdi_promedio.append(promedio / contador)
    promedio = 0
edad_promedio = np.delete(edad_promedio, (len(edad_promedio) - 1))
eNdi_promedio = np.delete(eNdi_promedio, )
plt.scatter(edad_promedio, eNdi_promedio, s=50, color="black", edgecolors='black')
```

This is, `edad_promedio = np.arange(140, 360, step=5)` and `eNdi_promedio` is the mean of `eNdi` values in each step.

Some of the values of `eNdi_promedio` are equal to zero because there's no data (I'm working with a database), so I want to exclude them from my scatter plot which is the one on the image:

[image]

Comment: Try `mask = eNdi_promedio != 0` then pass `plt.scatter(edad_promedio[mask], eNdi_promedio[mask], ...`

Comment: Thanks, I made `eNdi_promedio = ma.masked_equal(eNdi_promedio, 0)`